# Check CPU for AES support during custom-CentOS installation

Tags: centos

I have custom distribution of CentOS Linux 6.3. The installed system needs CPU support for AES-NI for all services to work properly.

**Can I add a check for AES support during the installation?** I'm using Anaconda, but am willing to consider other ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) for this answer:

This would require a kickstart script to be used. Fortunately the kickstart script need only be trivial. You may use this alone (for an otherwise normal interactive installation) or as part of an existing kickstart script.

```
%pre --erroronfail
#!/bin/sh
grep -q aes /proc/cpuinfo || exit 1
%end
```

If the CPU doesn't show this feature, the script will error exit and the installation will stop.

Comment: I'd go for `grep -q -E '^flags.* aes( |$)'` or similar. Might be overkill, but grepping aes verbatim may in theory cause false matches if those letters occur elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/proc/cpuinfo` for aes in flags. Alternatively, you could try loading the aesni-intel module (which might fail if unsupported), and/or check `/proc/crypto` if it lists aes as the aes-ni flavour.

Comment: I need get this information before OS installation. I want that installer check this CPU options.

Comment: So... doesn't this installer run in a Linux environment? Or your question is how to make this particular installer run additional checks in general?